# XML Document Parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml

I need to parse an XML document in java for a web service I'm making, and save the contents of it.

I need to save the name of the tags, if the tag has attributes save the attributes, and then save the data within those tags. These three items will be inserted into a database table with the three columns tags, attributes, and data.

I'm using the following java libraries:

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
org.w3c.dom.Document, org.w3c.dom.NodeList
org.xml.sax.InputSource.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So... Where is your code which does what you want? Did you try to write it or you just want that somebody do it for you?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## DISCLAIMER: I don't want to plagiarize so I didn't include code but included links to other tutorials that are VERY helpful to this topic.

**First**, you should read w3c dom's java API because it tells you a lot of useful functions that are very related to your question.

**Second**, *[this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)* website contains a useful tutorial that's easy to understand and it contains the necessary information for you to get the attributes of tags.

**Third**, *[this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.w3c.dom/ElementStringgetTagName.htm)* website gives you info on how to get tagName when you are looping through elements.

**Fourth**, you should always read related API, google, and then post a question if you are have no clue after a LONG period of time.

**Lastly**, you should post a difference question or research on database FIRST before asking that question here. This question should only be about XML Document Parsing in Java.

We are not supposed to help you do anything so the API is the best help for you (and google).

API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html